# HTTPS Redirection in wildfly Undertow

Tags: https, wildfly, undertow

I have ported my current website (from JBOSS7) to wildfly. But Using wildfly, I couold not maintain the HTTPSession in firefox & Chrome. Is there any problem with the wildfly Undertow implementaion or should I need to do any additional configuration for this apart from the default config.

Side Note: My context is in HTTPS redirection, following is the snippet of my standalone.xml file.

```
     <security-realm name="MyRealm">
            <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" path="\.keystore" 
                                                         keystore-password="changeit"/>
            </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>

 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="MyRealm"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" 
                  header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Venkat
```

Answer (score 3):

Add "redirect-socket="https"" to your http connector.